# OkHTTP Post Error 405

Tags: android, python, http, flask, okhttp

I'm trying to send data from an Android device to a web server using Flask. 
I'm just testing by returning some strings. 

If I do a post request on POSTMAN to `IP_Address/playlists` with `{"spotify_token":"test token"}` I'll get the proper response. `{"result":"received token"}`

But if I try to send a similar HTTP Post request on Android with OkHTTP I get error 405. `192.168.0.105 - - [19/Jul/2018 17:23:37] "POST //playlists HTTP/1.1" 405 -`

Response from server:

```html
Allow: HEAD, GET, OPTIONS
    Content-Length: 178
    Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/3.7.0
    Date: Fri, 20 Jul 2018 01:57:56 GMT
    <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
    <title>405 Method Not Allowed</title>
    <h1>Method Not Allowed</h1>
    <p>The method is not allowed for the requested URL.</p>
```

I checked my code with other answers and as far as I can tell it looks correct.. Also, I'm able to do a GET request in my home page fine.

Android Code

```
private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");

    public void onClick(View view){
        client = new OkHttpClient();
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("UserId", "test token");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString());

        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(IP_ADDRESS + "/playlists")
                .post(requestBody)
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                Log.e("ExportButton", e.toString());
            }
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                Log.e("ExportButton", response.body().string());
                if(response.isSuccessful()){
                    final String myResponse = response.body().string();
                    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            messageWindow.setText(myResponse);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
```

Flask code

```
    @app.route('/playlists', methods =["POST"])
    def get_playlists():
        data = request.get_json()
        spotify_token = data['spotify_token']
        print(spotify_token)
        return jsonify({'result': 'received token'})
```

Comment: What is the JSON in RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(JSON, jsonObject.toString()) ? Can you post the request logs and its headers?

Comment: sorry, my JSON was a final I declared outside
`private static final MediaType JSON = MediaType.parse("application/json; charset=utf-8");` <p>I updated the post with the error response header

Answer (score 0):

I printed out the response and found the full URL it was going to was "http://IP_Address//playlists" (there were two "/"s which is why it was getting the error.

Thanks Mushtu.